# Error handling of batch script with adb commands

Tags: android, batch-file, adb

I want to make a simple batch script to install apk on android device. I can do this if Debugging is on and Device drivers are installed.

When device drivers are not installed it show error device not found and when debug acces is not allowed it show please allow usb debug from device.

I want to know how i can switch between these errors i want to start adbdriverinstaller.exe if no drivers are installed and if it requires usb debug access then just echo please allow usb debug access form mobile.

Here is my code

```
@ECHO off

echo Writing Configuration... 

adb push Config.cfg /sdcard/Config.cfg
if errorlevel 1 echo Failed with error #%errorlevel%.

//here i want to switch between error types (if no device found error or allow usb debug access error)

if errorlevel 1 start "" AdbDriverInstaller.exe
if errorlevel 1 PAUSE
if errorlevel 1 EXIT

echo Installing Apk... 
adb install -r myApk.apk

echo opening apk

adb shell am start -n com.myApk.myApk/.myApkActivity

PAUSE
```

what i want to do is 
if

```
error: device not found
error: device not found
```

error arises then simply open adbdriver installer and if

```
error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.

error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

Error arises than simply display please allow USB debug access from mobile.

[image]

Comment: your logic is flawed. `error: device not found` does not necessarily mean that you need to install the driver

Comment: yes i know it will also happen if no device is connected but i a am comfortable with that i want to pause if usb access required and show this message else shaow a message if want to install driver or not

Answer (score 0):

`ADB` on its own does not tell why it could not find the device. But you could use `powershell "gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice"` to get status of USB devices in Windows. This allows you to find all enumerated `adb` interfaces and check whether they have appropriate drivers installed. For details read [adb device detection in Windows](http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html)